# Mathematica not solving $y'(x)=y(1/x)$ unless I rewrite it as $x^2y''(x)+y(x)=0$

Tags: differential-equations

So recently I have been practicing solving differential equations using Mathematica, and have currently been trying to solve a diff. eq. that I did solve fully on my own before that I asked about on Math.SE$$y'(x)=y(1/x)$$Now I am aware that the solution for this is$$y(x)=\sqrt x\left(c_1\cos\left(\dfrac{\sqrt3\ln x}2\right)+c_2\sin\left(\dfrac{\sqrt3\ln x}2\right)\right)$$<sub>(and if we take $c_1=1,c_2=i$, we can rewrite this as $y(x)=\sqrt xe^{(i\sqrt3\ln x)/2}$)</sub>

however I wanted to try solving this fully in Mathematica. Right away, I noticed that

```
DSolve[y'[x]==y[1/x],y,x]
```

did not seem to work, as it gave this error

```
DSolve: To avoid possible ambiguity, the arguments of the dependent variable in {y'[x]=y[1/x]} should literally match the independent variables.
```

however if I rewrote it as

```
DSolve[x^2y''[x]+y[x]==0,y,x]
```

it would give the correct solution.

---

[screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4vwf.png)

---

However, I would like to just solve $y'(x)=y(1/x)$ directly using Mathematica, so is this possible to do, or is there nothing I could do to avoid having to first write it as $x^2y''(x)+y(x)=0$ before solving using Mathematica?

Comment: what exactly is the independent variable in your ode? I am also very confused how did you obtain $x^2 y''+y=0$ from $y'(x)=y(1/x)$ ? Could you show these steps to make things more clear? I have never seen ode like $y'(x)=y(1/x)$ before. How did this come up?

Comment: **Now I am aware that the solution for this is** How?

Comment: Differential equations is very broad topic. Ordinary and partial differential equation are the most common. You are asking about the class of *functional differential equations*. Matematica knows about the *delay differential equations* class, which is a subclass. But that's about it.

Comment: @Nasser Just differentiate the original equation.

Comment: @yarchik  OK, but this is what Mathematica gives  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vNjz.png)  which is $x^2 y''(x) + y'(\frac{1}{x})=0$ which is not the same as $x^2 y''(x) +y(x) = 0 $. I hope you agree.   $y(x)$ is not the same as $y(\frac{1}{x})$ ?

Comment: @Nasser now use the original equation to express $y'(1/x)$ in terms of $y(x)$

Comment: It is interesting that the advertised solution does not seem to satisfy the functional differential equation [**`after a quick check`**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wraR5.png)

Comment: @yarchik But in $y'(1/x)$ the prime denotes differentiation with respect to $x$ or $1/x$? I mean, if you want to $x\to 1/x$ in $y'(x)=y(1/x)$ you need to consider $dx$, too.

Comment: @corey979 $y'(x)=y(1/x)\implies y'(1/x)=y(1/(1/x))=y(x)$. You don't need to consider $dx$. It's simple substitution

Comment: A power series expansion of `y'[x] - y[1/x]` about `x = 1` has a very small, and possibly zero, radius of convergence.

Comment: @CrSb0001 $y'(x)=dy(x)/dx \Rightarrow y'(1/x)=dy(1/x)/d(1/x)=dy(1/x)/dx * dx/d(1/x)=y'(1/x)*1/[d(1/x)/dx]=y'(1/x)*(-1/x^2)$

Comment: @corey979 You do realize I did go over that step in [my original question on this on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4817485/is-fx-f1-x-solvable), right?

Comment: @CrSb0001 You linked to it only in the comment in which you're asking if I've seen it, so - of course I haven't seen it. You should provide all necessary information and resources in the question.

Comment: @corey979 ah my bad

Comment: I thought you knew this already (or the equivalent): `Solve[y'[x] == y[1/x] /. First@DSolve[x^2 y''[x] + y[x] == 0, y, x] // Simplify[#, x > 0] &, {C[1], C[2]}] // FullSimplify` — that is, I thought you were trying to avoid `x^2 y''[x] + y[x] == 0`, as it says in the question, but that's exactly what the accepted question solves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking all the hints in the comments we get the solution `Y[x]` of the differentiated ode `odeD`

```
ode = y'[x] - y[1/x]

odeD = D[ode, x] /. y' -> Function[u, y[1/u]] // Simplify
Y = DSolveValue[odeD == 0, y, x];
```

[image]

```
odeD == 0 /. y -> Function[x, Y[x]] // Simplify[#, x > 0] & (* True*)
ode == 0 /. y -> Function[x, Y[x]] // Simplify[#, x > 0] &
(*(C[1] - Sqrt[3] C[2]) Cos[1/2 Sqrt[3] Log[x]] + (Sqrt[3] C[1] - 3 C[2]) Sin[1/2 Sqrt[3] Log[x]] == 0*)
```

As we can see `Y[x]` fullfills the differentiated `odeD` but not the original `ode`, which is only fullfilled if we set `C[1] -> Sqrt[3] C[2]`!

```
Y[x] /.  C[1] -> Sqrt[3] C[2]
(*Sqrt[3] Sqrt[x] C[2] Cos[1/2 Sqrt[3] Log[x]] +Sqrt[x] C[2] Sin[1/2 Sqrt[3] Log[x]]*)
```

[image]

That is the  solution of  `y'[x]==y[1/x]` (only one free parameter C[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghT08.png) to fullfill initial conditions!) QP asked for I think.

Answer (score 5):

The following approach works in this case because the functions $g(x)$ that appear in $y^{(k)}(g(x))$ in the ODE form a finite group under composition:

```
tgroup = {{x -> x}, {x -> 1/x}}; (* transformation group *)
DSolve[
 Eliminate[
  NestList[D[#, x] &, y'[x] == y[1/x], 1] /. tgroup // Flatten,
  {y[1/x], y'[1/x], y''[1/x]}],
 y, x]
(*
{{y -> Function[{x}, 
    Sqrt[x] C[1] Cos[1/2 Sqrt[3] Log[x]] + 
     Sqrt[x] C[2] Sin[1/2 Sqrt[3] Log[x]]]}}
*)
```

I don't know a theory that says how many time one has to differentiate the ODE, but the following seems to work no matter how many times I differentiate this first-order DE:

```
tgroup = {{x -> x}, {x -> 1/x}};
order = Length@tgroup;
DSolve[
 0 == First@GroebnerBasis[
    NestList[D[#, x] &, y'[x] == y[1/x], order] /. tgroup // Flatten,
    Table[Derivative[k][y][x], {k, order + 1, 0, -1}],
    Table[Derivative[k][y][x], {k, 0, order + 1}] /. Rest@tgroup // Flatten],
 y, x]
(*
{{y -> Function[{x}, 
    Sqrt[x] C[1] Cos[1/2 Sqrt[3] Log[x]] + 
     Sqrt[x] C[2] Sin[1/2 Sqrt[3] Log[x]]]}}
*)
```

As @yarchik mentioned in a comment, `DSolve` does not handle functional differential equations, except for DDEs.

---

Bonus illustration:  `y'[x] == y[1/(1 - x)]`
(Warning: it takes a few minutes to calculate the Gröbner basis):

```
tgroup = {{x -> x}, {x -> 1/(1 - x)}, {x -> (-1 + x)/x}};
order = Length@tgroup;
DSolve[
 0 == First@GroebnerBasis[
    NestList[D[#, x] &, y'[x] == y[1/(1 - x)], order] /. tgroup // 
      Flatten // Simplify,
    Table[Derivative[k][y][x], {k, order + 1, 0, -1}]; {},
    Table[Derivative[k][y][x], {k, order + 1, 0, -1}] /. Rest@tgroup //
      Flatten],
 y, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The slowness indicates this may not be a robust approach.